# How I can convert for loop in python using map function

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

this is the code that I want to convert it using map function in python

```
for joint_word in joint_words:
    if joint_word in wordset:
        # word in joint_words found in sentence, just populate the index
        wovec[i] = windex[joint_word]
    else:
        sim_word, max_sim = most_similar_word(joint_word, wordset)
        if max_sim > ETA:
            wovec[i] = windex[sim_word]
        else:
            wovec[i] = 0
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: This would not be an appropriate use of `map()`. `map()` creates a list of the results of a function, but you're not creating a list here.

Comment: Well, assuming `i` started out as 0, yes, they really are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the raw translation would be:

```
def lookup(word):
    if word in wordset:
        return windex[word]
    sim_word, max_sim = most_similar_word(word, wordset)
    return windex[sim_word] if max_sim > ETA else 0

wovec = list(map(lookup, joint_words))
```

If `wovec` will be used as an iterable, then you don't need the cast to `list`.

Comment: Without the call to list, it will only be usable once

Comment: Right, hence my warning about using it as an iterable.

Comment: I did warn OP to select your answer. Twice.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8+, you can take the simple function [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562171/2988730) made, and turn it into a one-line abomination:

```
wovec = list(map(lambda word: windex[word] if word in wordset else (windex[msw[0]] if ((msw := most_similar_word(word, wordset))[1]) > ETA else 0), joint_words))
```

Basically, don't unpack the result of `most_similar_word(word, wordset)`, instead assign it within the expression and access by index. Enjoy!

In case it wasn't clear, I'm endorsing Tim's answer. Please don't ever use something like what I wrote. Not to mention that comprehensions generally tend to be marginally faster than maps.

Comment: Thank you Both , I select Time's answer